# React Typescript - Types are incompatible with Thrid Party Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have a third party library that export a React Component like this:

```
// Code I can not change
export default class MyIcon extends React.Component {
...
};

MyIcon.propTypes = {
  color?: PropTypes.String
}
```

I'm working on Typescript so I made the definition for this module:

```
// Code I can change
declare module '@thirdparty/MyIcon' {
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
color?: string
}

const Icon: React.FC<Props>;
export default Icon;
```

Now, there is a typescript Component that has this structure:

```
// Code I can not change
interface IButton {
icon?: React.Component,
text: string
}

export default const Button: FC<IButton> = ({ icon, text }) => {...}
```

Everything works good till I want to use the MyIcon component and pass it through the Button component. The error I get is `Type React.FC<Props> is incompatible with Component<{}, {}, {}>`

I endup doing this:

`<Button icon={myIcon as unknown as Component} />`

But what it kills me is not knowing why is failing.

**ANSWER**

After talking with the creator of the third party libraries I found they are having the type as Component because they need to change it internally. But doing this, they force my other third party library to behave as a class and not a ReactNode. So basically typing the Icon will work for one of the Third party libraries but it won't allow me to use the other third party library in my project, See code below:

```
// Ok Code
<Button icon={MyIcon}>Works</Button>

// Wrong Code
<div><MyIcon /> Error on Typescript</div>
```

Clearly the problem was not the type, but the problem is the way one of the third party libs is requiring the Icon to be a Component instead of a ReactNode. This in my case made a whole problem for me. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: you could use `icon: typeOf MyIcon` directly.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: Where did you use `Icon` defined in the module that you can change?

Comment: That's just a declaration of the type. So, I'm just trying to use 2 libraries. One library is the Icon one and the second library is a component that receives an Icon as a prop. Both libraries are third party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are using `React.FC` for Icon, but Icon is a class component not a Functional component

try

```
const Icon: React.Component<Props>
```

Comment: It does not work I keep getting an error, I already try Component<Props>, ComponentType<Props>, ComponentClassic<Props>. If I use those the error I get is  ' The Expression is not callable'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of requiring a class-based component, you could just type `icon` to allow any node:

```
interface IButton {
  icon?: React.Node,
  text: string
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I already try that and that works, but that means to fork a third party library just to change a type. But the question is more why is failing with Component and how should be define the type to work as It's originally define.

Comment: The third party library likely just has the wrong types. I don't think there's a reasonable solution here.

Comment: at this point I'm so close to contact the author of the library to ask him directly about it. The problem is I'm not sure he is still working at the company. But my guess after 2 days trying to figure it out was the same.. there must be something wrong with their types.

Comment: I gave you the points because indeed, the problem was with the library instead of a typescript issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here you've said that `Icon` is of type `React.FC<Props>`

```
const Icon: React.FC<Props>;
```

But here you've said that you expect `icon` to be either `undefined` or `React.Component`.

```
icon?: React.Component,
```

`React.FC` != `React.Component`.

Change your code to:

```
icon?: React.FC<Props>
```

You'd likely need to export that interface:

```
// icon.tsx

export interface IconProps {
  // types here
}
```

So that you can use it in external modules.

Comment: I think I was not really clear with my question, I just add some comments to be more specific about the code I can change

Comment: Multiple people have already given you your problem... React.Component and React.FC are not the same thing, either make it a component or make it a functional component.  Don't mix up the two between your types and actual component.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this example could work but you could try to change types in typescript like this.

```
interface X {
    icon: boolean;
}

interface Y extends Omit<X,"icon">{
    icon: string; 
}
```

Comment: This basically creates a new interface Y from X omitting the field "icon" from X and using field "icon" as defined in interface Y.